# Cocos2D Template is not visible in xcode 4.3.3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded

cocos2d-cocos2d-iphone-release-2.0-0-g02cebb5.tar.gz

Executed: ./install-templates.sh -f

Command but templets are still not visible in Xcode 4.3.3.

Can any one help me.